# How do I flatten a nested json key/value pair into a single array of values?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In SNOWFLAKE, I have a data structure like:

```
ORGANIZATION TABLE
------------------
Org:variant
------------------
{
    relationships: [{
        { name: 'mother', value: a },
        { name: 'siblings', value: [ 'c', 'd' ] }
    }]
}

PEOPLE TABLE
-------------------
Person:variant
-------------------
{
    id: a
    name: Mary
}
-------------------
{
    id: b
    name: Joe
}
-------------------
{
    id: c
    name: John
}
```

I want to have a result of:

```
ORGANIZATION                                       | PEOPLE
---------------------------------------------------|----------------------------
{                                                  |[
    relationships: [{                              |  {
        { name: 'mother', value: a },              |    id: a,
        { name: 'siblings', value: [ 'c', 'd' ] }  |    name: Mary
    }]                                             |  },
}                                                  |  {
                                                   |    id: b,
                                                   |    name: Joe
                                                   |  },
                                                   |  {
                                                   |    id: c,
                                                   |    name: john
                                                   |  }
                                                   |]
```

I'm sure ARRAY_AGG is involved somehow but I'm at a loss how I would aggregate the results up into a single array of values.

My current query:

```
SELECT Org, ARRAY_AGG(Person) as People
FROM Organizations
INNER JOIN People ON People.id IN Org.relationships...?? (I'm lost here)
GROUP BY Org
```

Comment: Also see [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: I did tag the vendor: snowflake

Comment: never mind that comment i never heard of snowflake and offcource it didn't hold mine mouse on the tag to read it.. i was thinking snowflake was some kind of programming framework

Comment: After mousing-over myself, I am using the wrong platform tag anyways

Comment: can you eborate the expected results also as the expected results are still "obfuscated" with `org record | array of person records` ...

Comment: `ARRAY_AGG` is SQL function to work with anny datatype array expect not a JSON array ... You need to be looking [here](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions-semistructured.html) .. i can't help you futher as i don't have acces to a snowflake database server..

Comment: Also see [JSON Data Parsing in Snowflake](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/json-data-parsing-in-snowflake)

Comment: I updated the question to be a little more clear. I have thoroughly dived into the documentation though, before coming here.

Comment: How to analyse json with sql (for snowflake) https://www.snowflake.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/Snowflake-How-to-Analyze-JSON-with-SQL.pdf

Comment: Your example _really_ requires the expected result that matches your data.

Comment: I added an updated example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The below queries illustrate how to use FLATTEN and ARRAY_AGG to get the output you want.

- FLATTEN unnests each array so that you can join on the values within.
- ARRAY_AGG aggregates the values grouped by org.
- The CASE statement accounts for org.relationships not always being an array.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE organizations (org variant) AS
SELECT parse_json('{relationships: [{ name: "mother", value: "a" }, { name: "siblings", value: [ "b", "c" ] } ] } ');


CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE people (person variant) AS
SELECT parse_json($1)
FROM
VALUES ('{id:"a", name: "Mary"}'),
       ('{id:"b", name: "Joe"}'), 
       ('{id:"c", name: "John"}');

WITH org_people AS
  (SELECT o.org,
          relationship.value AS relationship,
          CASE is_array(relationship:value)
              WHEN TRUE THEN person_in_relationship.value
              ELSE relationship:value
          END AS person_in_relationship
   FROM organizations o,
        LATERAL FLATTEN(o.org:relationships) relationship ,
        LATERAL FLATTEN(relationship.value:value, OUTER=>TRUE) person_in_relationship
  )
SELECT op.org,
       ARRAY_AGG(p.person) AS people
FROM org_people op
JOIN people p ON p.person:id = op.person_in_relationship
GROUP BY op.org;
```